# phalcon file upload fail

Tags: php, phalcon

I have tried to upload file into server. But where it doesn't work that.
This is my form.

```
<form action="index/upload" method="POST">
    <label>File</label>
    <input type="file" name="upFile">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();
    if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true) {
        foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file){
               echo $file->getName(), ' ', $file->getSize(), '\n';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'File not uploaded';
    }
}
```

But it always return "File not uploaded".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your php code is correct, the problem lies in your html. You should add the correct encoding to your form:

```
<form action="index/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

More info here: [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: Mistakes like that happen a lot. You can mark question as solved or even delete it, since its just a silly mistake on your side :)